# Как настроить всплывающее окно с fancybox после нажатия button с

Tags: php, javascript, form, fancybox, всплывающее-окно

Есть форма:

```html
<form class="order-form" method="post" action="" id="contact">

  <div class="FormGroup">
    <input type="text" name="fl_name" placeholder="Представьтесь">
  </div>
  <div class="FormGroup">
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Из какого Вы города">
  </div>
  <div class="FormGroup">
    <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="тел. 050-000-00-00">
  </div>
  <div class="FormGroup">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Заказать сейчас</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Подскажите плз, как после отправки формы открыть окно с блоком `<div id="thx">` на 5-10 секунд и пропадало, планирую сделать на fancybox

Планирую использовать:

```js
$('#send').submit(function(e) {
$.fancybox({
    href: '#thx', 
    modal: true
});
return false;
});
```

Но открытие так и не происходит....

Comment: гуглите в сторону `$.ajax`

Comment: http://xozblog.ru/demo/modal-windows/

Comment: Добавил в скрипт-файл такой код: `$("#send").on("click", function(){

   $("#thx").fancybox({
     maxHeight : 600,
     fitToView : false,
     width   : '90%',
     height    : 'auto',
     autoSize  : false,
     closeClick  : false,
     openEffect  : 'none',
     closeEffect : 'none'
    });

 }); ` - пока ничего не получилось (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил сам:
в конце php функции добавил код `sleep(5);`

а скрипт такой:

```js
$('.send').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize('#contact'),
    success: function(data) {
      $.fancybox({
        href: '#thx',
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        afterLoad: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            parent.$.fancybox.close({
              closeEffect: 'elastic'
            });
          }, 3000);
        }
      });

    }
  });
});
```

может кому пригодится....

Comment: Это неправильное решение данной задачи, хоть и рабочее. Верно было бы откладывать время выполнения клиентского кода, а не серверного.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #thx {
      position: fixed;
      width: 200px;
      left: 50%;
      padding: 50px 100px;
      border: 3px solid #eee;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.order-form').submit(function(event) {

        $("#thx").css('margin-left', -$("#thx").outerWidth() / 2); // Выравниваем по центру окно относительно его ширины

        $("#thx").fadeIn(500); // Показываем окно

        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#thx").fadeOut(500); // Скрываем его
        }, 5000); // 5000 = 5 секунд

        event.preventDefault(); // Отменяет отправку формы. Это вместо retrun false; Хотя может я не правильно понял зачем вы использовали return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="order-form" method="post">
    <div class="FormGroup">
      <input type="text" name="fl_name" placeholder="Представьтесь">
    </div>
    <div class="FormGroup">
      <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Из какого Вы города">
    </div>
    <div class="FormGroup">
      <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="тел. 050-000-00-00">
    </div>
    <div class="FormGroup">
      <button type="submit" name="submit">Заказать сейчас</button>
    </div>
    <div id="thx" style="display:none">
      Контент
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

## UPDATE

```
$('.send').click(function() {
    var timeout = 5000;

    $.fancybox({
        href: '#thx',
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic'
    });

    SetTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close({ href: '#thx' });", timeout);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize('#contact'),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
        });
    }, timeout);
});
```

Comment: Да, действительно, тут `event.preventDefault();` отменяется отправка  -отказался от него. но в вашем коде не используется плагин `.fancybox`. Мне бы хотелось использовать именно его.

Comment: Я использовал вот такой код: `$('.send').click(function(){
        //e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
    type: $(this).attr('method'),
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize('#contact'),
    success: function(data){
     $.fancybox({
      href: '#thx',
      openEffect    : 'elastic',
      closeEffect    : 'elastic'
     });
     SetTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close({ href: '#thx' });", 5000);
    }
   });
  });` Сменив в кнопке использование id на class, но тут у меня не успевает сработать `SetTimeout`, так как письмо отправляется и окно обновляется.

Comment: Посмотрите мой "Ответ на комментарий" в ответе. Я не проверял свой код, но меня смущает строка SetTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close({ href: '#thx' });", interval);

Comment: К сожалению задержка так и не произошла. строка `SetTimeout("parent.$.fancybox.close({ href: '#thx' });", interval);` должна автоматически закрывать окно. Может есть возможность открыть окно уже после отрабатывания php-функции, отправки формы?